# HTML5 / CSS3 Circle with Partial Border

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

Is it possible to create a circle using only HTML5 / CSS3 which has a border that only goes part way around the circle? If not, what techniques can I use to accomplish this effect? I would prefer to use pure DOM elements, but if I have to I can draw on canvas or spin up an SVG.

Comment: what's "part way"? 1/4, 1/2, 3/4? or something more arbitrary?

Comment: Something which can be smoothly animated from 0% to 100% around the circle.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

### 2023 solution

This method requires no JS, no extra element and not even any pseudos, just a handful of CSS declarations. It also works if the element has a (semi)transparent `background` in addition to this partial `border`.

It uses a two layer `mask`, one being a `conic-gradient` which creates a visible pie selection and whose size is relative to the `border-box` and the second being a simple full cover layer restricted to the `padding-box`.

First, we make our element circular (arbitrary `width`, an `aspect-ratio` of `1` and a `border-radius` set to `50%`) and give it a `border`.

Then, we set a `mask` that's a `conic-gradient()`, relative to the `border-box`, covering a percentage `--p` of our element (by default starting from 12 o'clock and going clockwise).

On top of this `mask` layer, we set a full cover one restricted to the `padding-box`.

```css
.circular-progress {
  border: solid 1.5em hotpink;
  width: 50vmin;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: hsla(180, 100%, 50%, .5);
  --mask: 
    linear-gradient(red, red) padding-box, 
    conic-gradient(red var(--p, 17%), transparent 0%) border-box;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask)
}

/* just to make it obvious it works with semitrasparent background */
body {
  background: 
    url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1693483923875-cdd9ef4a8046?w=800) 
      50%/ cover
}
```

```html
<div class='circular-progress'></div>
```

If we want to animate this, we need to also register `--p`.

```css
@property --p {
  syntax: '<percentage>';
  initial-value: 0%;
  inherits: true
}

.circular-progress {
  border: solid 1.5em hotpink;
  width: 50vmin;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: hsla(180, 100%, 50%, .5);
  --mask: 
    linear-gradient(red, red) padding-box, 
    conic-gradient(red var(--p), transparent 0%) border-box;
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
  animation: p 4s linear infinite
}

@keyframes p { to { --p: 100% } }

/* just to make it obvious it works with semitrasparent background */
body {
  background: 
    url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1693483923875-cdd9ef4a8046?w=800) 
      50%/ cover
}
```

```html
<div class='circular-progress'></div>
```

Registering custom properties this way in order to animate them is supported in Chromium browsers and in Safari and it's coming soonish in Firefox Nightly too.

---

### Original answer from 2012 (preserved for web history reasons)

Yes, it is possible - see this:

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 7em auto;
  width: 16em;
  height: 16em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: lightblue;
}

.arc {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  /* make sure top & left values are - the width of the border */
  /* the bottom right corner is the centre of the parent circle */
  top: -1em;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: -1em;
  /* the transform origin is the bottom right corner */
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  /* rotate by any angle */
  /* the skew angle is 90deg - the angle you want for the arc */
  transform: rotate(45deg) skewX(30deg);
}

.arc:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  border: solid 1em navy;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class='circle'>
  <div class='arc'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't make N-degree arc this way. Only 90,180 or 270.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but how do you change the length of the arc? KPthunder mentioned he wanted to be able to smoothly animate it from 0 - 100% around the circle.

Comment: You change the skew angle. The skew angle is `90deg - the angle of the arc`. But more than one element is going to be needed to make it fill an entire circle.

Comment: I could not make it work. Could you specify, please, which parameter should I change for arc to animated smoothly from 0% to 100% around the circle as required?

Comment: Was looking for a way to make half of the border on a circle transparent. This was the only method I could find that works. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

It's possible.

- Draw two circles using `border-radius` one on top of another.
- Make one or more arc of both circles `transparent` by changing `border-color`.
- Use `transform` to rotate the second circle and you will have the arc of the size you need.

Here is the **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kJXwZ/2/

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}

.arc {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.arc_start {
  border-color: transparent red red red;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.arc_end {
  border-color: red red red transparent;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(75deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(75deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(75deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(75deg);
  transform: rotate(75deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="arc arc_start"></div>
  <div class="arc arc_end"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't get less than 1/4 of a circle with this method though, since one of the border quarters will always be showing....

Comment: True, but you could less than 1/4 if instead of `transparent` you use the color of the background

Answer (score 13):

This uses JavaScript as well, so it breaks from the original requirement :(
.. it does however deliver

There is a >> [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ht5X7/2/) << here

@gkond Thanks, I derived this from your answer

```js
// create a circle using HTML5 / CSS3 / JS which has a border that only goes part-way around
// the circle .. and which can be smoothly animated from 0% to 100% around the circle

// this solution allows for animation and still results in relatively clean code
// we use four quarter-circles, all hidden away behind a white square to start with..
// all four are rotated out clockwise, and each quarter will stop at it's own maximum:
// q1 at 25%, q2 at 50% .. etc. once we reach a value at or over 25%, all four quarters
// should be out from behind the white square, and we can hide it.. it needs to be
// hidden if we display a value over 75%, or else q4 will end up going in behind it again
// .. also, since the top border will usually sit between the angles of  -45 to 45, we
// rotate everything by an extra -45 to make it all line up with the top nicely

var fromHidden = -90;

// utility function to align 0 degrees with top
// takes degrees and returns degrees - 45
function topAlign(degrees) {
  return degrees - 45
};

// utility function to rotate a jQuery element
// takes element and the degree of rotation (from the top) 
function rotate(el, degrees) {
  var degrees = topAlign(degrees || 0);
  el.css(
    'transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
    '-webkit-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
    '-moz-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
    '-ms-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)',
    '-o-transform', 'rotate(' + degrees + 'deg)'
  )
}

// function to draw semi-circle
// takes a jQuery element and a value (between 0 and 1)
// element must contain four .arc_q elements
function circle(el, normalisedValue) {
  var degrees = normalisedValue * 360; // turn normalised value into degrees
  var counter = 1; // keeps track of which quarter we're working with
  el.find('.arc_q').each(function() { // loop over quarters..
    var angle = Math.min(counter * 90, degrees); // limit angle to maximum allowed for this quarter
    rotate($(this), fromHidden + angle); // rotate from the hiding place
    counter++; // track which quarter we'll be working with in next pass over loop
  });
  if (degrees > 90) { // hide the cover-up square soon as we can
    el.find('.arc_cover').css('display', 'none');
  }
}

// uses the the circle function to 'animate' drawing of the semi-circle
// incrementally increses the value passed by 0.01 up to the value required
function animate(el, normalisedValue, current) {
  var current = current || 0;
  circle(el, current);
  if (current < normalisedValue) {
    current += 0.01;
    setTimeout(function() {
      animate(el, normalisedValue, current);
    }, 1);
  }
}

// kick things off ..
animate($('.circle'), 0.69);
```

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
}

.arc_q {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-color: transparent green transparent transparent;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.arc_cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle">
  <div class="arc_q"></div>
  <div class="arc_q"></div>
  <div class="arc_q"></div>
  <div class="arc_q"></div>
  <div class="arc_cover"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh awesome - thank you so much! Just used on a website I'm building - will attribute to you in the code :)

Answer (score 5):

Conic gradient solution (works for any degree):

```css
:root{
--degree:80deg;
--smoothing:0.5deg;
--color:red;
}

.a{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
border-radius:50%;
background: conic-gradient(
     var(--color) var(--degree), transparent calc(var(--degree) + var(--smoothing)) 100%);

}

.b{
  height:84%;
  width:84%;
  top:8%;
  left:8%;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#D3D3D3;
}
```

```html
<div class ="a">
    <div class="b">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you can use simple box border properties, one element and one class. This would be an inline, inline-block or block treatment, depending on where you place your easy-circle class, and how/if you style position.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.easy-circle {
    background: transparent;
    border: 1em solid black; /* color not required, may show device fail */
    border-color: red green blue transparent;
    height: 10em;
    width: 10em;
    -moz-border-radius: 6em; /* height/2 + border thickness */
    -webkit-border-radius: 6em;
    border-radius: 50%; /* more than 50, shape-size adjustment irrelevant */
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
     transform: rotate(45deg); /* transform optional */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="easy-circle">
</div>​
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved setting a transparent border around a transparent circle and using `border-top-color: ;` to give a section of the circles border a color.

```
background-color:transparent;
border:3px solid transparent;
border-top-color: green;
```

This creates a circle with a border only around the top quarter;

You can also use

```
border-bottom-color:green;
```

as well as left and right to border different quarters of the circles circumference.

Here's a fiddle for a loader with 3 partial circles that spin inside each other in alternate directions that show this in action.

[Here's a fiddle for a loader with 3 partial circles that spin inside each other in alternate directions that show this in action.](https://jsfiddle.net/seanculleng/9bj6fgqk/33/)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to animate this is using css keyframes.

http://jsfiddle.net/8SUPX/644/

```css
/**
 * HTML5 / CSS3 Circle with Partial Border
 * http://stackoverflow.com/q/13059190/1397351
 */
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
.circle {
 position: relative;
 margin: 6em auto;
 width: 12em; height: 12em;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: transparent;
 border:20px solid #efefef;
 border-top-color: #efefef;
    border-right-color: #efefef;
    border-bottom-color: #efefef;
    border-left-color: #efefef;
    
    -webkit-transition:.5s;-moz-transition:.5s;transition:.5s;
}
.circle:hover{
      -webkit-animation:  animix 0.5s 1;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      -moz-animation:  animix 0.5s 1;
      -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      animation:  animix 0.5s 1;
      animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}



  //Animate
   @-webkit-keyframes animix {
    0% { 
      border-top-color: transparent;
      border-right-color: transparent;
      border-bottom-color: transparent;
      border-left-color: transparent;
    }
     25% { 
       border-top-color: red;
       border-right-color: transparent;
       border-bottom-color: transparent;
       border-left-color: transparent;
     }
     50% { 
       border-top-color: red;
       border-right-color: red;
       border-bottom-color: transparent;
       border-left-color: transparent;
     }
     75% { 
       border-top-color: red;
       border-right-color: red;
       border-bottom-color: red;
       border-left-color: transparent;
     }
     100% { 
       border-top-color: red;
       border-right-color: red;
       border-bottom-color: red;
       border-left-color: red;
     }
   }
   
      @keyframes animix {
    0% { 
      border-top-color: transparent;
      border-right-color: transparent;
      border-bottom-color: transparent;
      border-left-color: transparent;
    }
     25% { 
       border-top-color: red;
       border-right-color: transparent;
       border-bottom-color: transparent;
       border-left-color: transparent;
     }
     50% { 
       border-top-color: red;
       border-right-color: red;
       border-bottom-color: transparent;
       border-left-color: transparent;
     }
     75% { 
       border-top-color: red;
       border-right-color: red;
       border-bottom-color: red;
       border-left-color: transparent;
     }
     100% { 
       border-top-color: red;
       border-right-color: red;
       border-bottom-color: red;
       border-left-color: red;
     }
   }
```

```html
<div class="circle"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want double border  you can use it also

```css
div
{
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin:  40px auto;
  color: black; 
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px; 
  border-radius: 50%; 
  position: relative;
}

div::before
{ 
  content: "";
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-10px, -10px);
  z-index: -1;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-color: red red red transparent;
}
body ::after
{
  content: "";
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-21px, -22px);
  z-index: -8;
  border: 12px solid;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: blue transparent blue blue;
}
```

```html
<div> </div>
```

Comment: this one is useful, and to narrow the gap a little you can use double circles with different rotations.