# Making An Arc using css

Tags: html, css

I am new to this. I want to make a clock similar to the one given [here](http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2009/12/colorful-clock-jquery-css/demo.html). But they have used images. Instead I want to make use of **ARC**. Does anyone know, how can we make an arc, that too using only css? Consider an example that I have to make an arc of 15 degrees. Any kind of suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Not a CSS solution, but you could check out http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: http://4ppletree.me/en/blog-en/css3-only-arc/

Comment: This is a nice example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059190/html5-css3-circle-with-partial-border

Comment: you should read more about transform:rotate which could help to  to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you use SVG to do this. The markup is fairly simple, but you'll need to stay aware that there are four different rules which affect which side of the two end points the bulge of the arc with lay and if the bulge will try to take the "short way" or the "long way" with the given radius.

Here's an example. Use a stylesheet like this:

```
.arc{
    fill:tan;
    stroke:red;
    stroke-width:4px;
}
```

combined with an svg path like this:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
    <path d="M 10,40 A 50,50 0 0 1 90,70"/>
</svg>
```

In short the commands in the above example are

- M (move mode with absolute coordinates)
- x,y (start the arc here here)
- A (arc mode with absolute coordinates)
- r1,r2 (the two radius of the ellipse that the arc goes around. use the same value twice for a circle)
- z rotation (the rotation of that ellipse. 0 is no rotation)
- large arc flag (see fiddle link below)
- sweep flag (see fiddle link below)
- x,y (where the arc will end)

I made this fiddle to demonstrate all the different combinations of the two flags in movement which helps me a lot in deciding which ones to use. http://jsfiddle.net/rgbk/avpye8nm

The W3C docs are here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands They describe z rotation as "x-axis-rotation" which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be CSS ? or could you use HTL5 canvas?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_arc.asp

then you could use that canvas to do the animation instead of using CSS animations...