# how to create circle that cut off one piece with css

Tags: html, css

I want create one circle with CSS that cut off one piece (like pizza :D) but I don't know about it. please guide me how to create one circle like pizza that one piece cut off.

this is my code :
**HTML:**

```
<div class="state"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.state {
position: absolute;
height: 44px;
width: 44px;
right: 5px;
top: 0;
border: 3px solid transparent;
border-radius: 25px;
z-index: 1;
border-color: #82ba00
}
```

I want create this image :

[image]

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059190/html5-css3-circle-with-partial-border

Comment: thanks my friend Can you tell me more about that?

Comment: CSS is the wrong tool for this kind of task. Use SVG or Canvas instead. It's designed for this kind of thing. CSS isn't. (yes, it may be possible to do it in CSS, but that doesn't mean you should do it in CSS).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the link RJo provided and the demo in one of the answers I came up with this:

```
<div class="arc-wrapper">
  <div class="arc arc_start"></div>    
  <div class="arc arc_end"></div>
</div>


.arc-wrapper {
position:relative;
margin:20px;
}
.arc {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius:100%;
border:1px solid;
border: 10px solid;
border-color: #82ba00;
}
.arc_start {
border-color:#82ba00  transparent;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-65deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-65deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-65deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-65deg);
transform: rotate(-65deg);
} 
.arc_end {
border-color: transparent #82ba00 #82ba00 #82ba00;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-110deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-110deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-110deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-110deg);
transform: rotate(-110deg);
}
```

You can change the size and direction of the gap by changing the `rotate(deg)` values.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mmetsalu/JmruQ/

Comment: +1: You've even got the angles right on the ends of the lines [of course, being an arc that's what you'd expect!  ;o) ].

Comment: Congratulations @martin-metsalu, you were faster! ;) But here is my solution, too: http://jsfiddle.net/Stocki/ttAyW/

Comment: Technically i was the first to post a solution, but i concede. this is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/cfhz9/)

Inspiration from magnifying glass shape from this [LINK](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

***EDIT:*** This is a adjustable arc too. So you can increase or decrease size of the circle only by making one change to this line in the CSS

```
font-size: 15em;  /* This controls the size. */
```

CSS

```
 #pie {
        font-size: 15em;
        /* This controls the size. */
        display: inline-block;
        width: 0.5em;
        height: 0.5em;
        border: 0.05em solid #00cc00;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 0.35em;
    }
    #pie::before {
        content:"";
        display: inline-block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0.33em;
        bottom: 0em;
        border-width: 0;
        background: white;
        width: 0.22em;
        height: 0.12em;
        -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="pie"><div>
```

***EDIT 2:***
Here is a fiddle of a Canvas based solution. Personally i feel you should use this method.
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/marsone/G3J5U/)**

Code borrowed from Tharindulucky

Answer (score 1):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/vqu5d/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="circle"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#circle {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 10px solid green;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
    transform:rotate(30deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it by using HTML5 Canvas element.

First write the code for cavas. (Just like a div.)

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

And then write the script for it

```
<script>
var d=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var dtx=d.getContext("2d");
dtx.beginPath();
dtx.arc(95,50,40,0,1.8*Math.PI);
dtx.lineWidth = 5;
dtx.stroke();
</script>
```

It will produce what you want. Have fun!

For more advanced reference, http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-circles/