# HTML arc sector with inline style

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I would like to use HTML + CSS to draw a arc sector with fixed radix and length (e.g. 30px radius and 70% length).

I found so far most of the solution is to combined two pictures with `position:absoulte`. Unfortunately, my html codes will be embedded as an email template to send out, and I found that Gmail does not support absolute position. And that is also the reason why I would like to use inline style rather than header css.

Related question here:
[HTML5 / CSS3 Circle with Partial Border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059190/html5-css3-circle-with-partial-border)

The similar output I am looking for.
http://dabblet.com/gist/3949571

Any help for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use an SVG.

```css
svg {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
circle.inner {
  stroke: rebeccapurple;
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke-dasharray: 39% 139%;
  stroke-dashoffset: 78%;
  fill: pink;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle class="inner" cx="40" cy="40" r="25" />

</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I'm not clear how to set the values to modify the arc length. Would you mind to further explain a little bit, with an example? (e.g. how to set to have arc degree 70)

Answer (score 0):

you can use transparent borders and inset shadow to draw bg color :

```css
/*demo*/
div {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;/* center content not text */
  text-align:center; 
  }
```

```html
<div style="
            box-sizing:border-box;
            padding:1px;
            margin:5px;
            height:200px;
            width:200px;
            border:solid 20px transparent;
            border-top-color:blue;
            box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 100px lightblue;
            border-radius:100%;"
     >Some text <br/> too?</div>
```