# How to use CSS to give a circle a "partial border"

Tags: html, css

Another user (@Simon Zhu) asked if it was possible to use CSS to create a circle with a "partial border" - especially a partial-border which arced around more than 90 degrees of the circle.

**See:** [How to create partial circle border in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838084/how-to-create-partial-circle-border-in-css)

The answer is yes - any arc is possible using `clip-path` and `border-radius` and the `::before` pseudo-element.

See answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 / CSS3 Circle with Partial Border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059190/html5-css3-circle-with-partial-border)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of:

- `clip-path: polygon()`
- `border-radius`
- `::before` pseudo-element

to create any partial circle border you wish.

**Working Example:**

```css
body {
width: 420px
}

.circle {
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 112px;
height: 112px;
margin: 6px 6px 12px 6px;
padding: 6px;
background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle::before {
content: '';
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 124px;
height: 124px;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.circle::after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin: 12px;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle:nth-of-type(1)::before {
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.circle:nth-of-type(2)::before {
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 30%, 50% 50%, 30% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.circle:nth-of-type(3)::before {
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 10%, 50% 50%, 10% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.circle:nth-of-type(4)::before {
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.circle:nth-of-type(5)::before {
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 30% 0%, 50% 50%, 30% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.circle:nth-of-type(6)::before {
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 10% 0%, 50% 50%, 10% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.circle:nth-of-type(7)::before {
clip-path: polygon(0% 10%, 50% 50%, 0% 90%, 0% 100%);
}

.circle:nth-of-type(8)::before {
clip-path: polygon(0% 30%, 50% 50%, 0% 70%, 0% 100%);
}

.circle:nth-of-type(9)::before {
clip-path: polygon(0% 45%, 50% 50%, 0% 55%, 0% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: This is not a cross-browser solution. Does not work in IE/Edge. https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path

Comment: It will work in Edge now, given that Edge adopted the Blink rendering engine (the same one used by Chrome and Opera) in early 2020.

Comment: This "solution" only works on a solid color background. It does not genuinely create a partial arc, it just mimics the look of one using a polygon to cover part of it up. This does not genuinely create a partial border as asked in the original question.

Comment: Yes, the CSS configuration above only works on a solid colour background.