# How to make not completed borders around an element in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want it to be like this shape [image: here].
Just tell me how to make the not completed borders.
And one last thing is that I have to use one div.`<div>Elzero</div>` with pseudo-elements
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 / CSS3 Circle with Partial Border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059190/html5-css3-circle-with-partial-border)

Comment: without pseudo-elements it would only be possible with the use of a background image or SVG

Comment: I can use pseudo-elements, but how could I use them to make this shape done?

Comment: if you can pseudo-elements, use the the link that has been posted above. They explain how to do it.

Comment: I appreciate you are required to use pseudo elements, but just a note that a background consisting of radial and conic gradients could probably do it (though without the pseudo elements, less animatable if needed).

Comment: Thank you all, It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

you can make it with transparent border

```css
div
{
  background-color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin:  40px auto;
  color: black; 
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px; 
  border-radius: 50%; 
  position: relative;
}

div::before
{ 
  content: "";
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-10px, -10px);
  z-index: -1;
  border: 10px solid;
  border-color: red red red transparent;
}
body ::after
{
  content: "";
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-21px, -22px);
  z-index: -8;
  border: 12px solid;
  background: transparent;
   border-color: blue transparent blue blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try That Bro :)

```
div {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
div::before{
  content: "";
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #03a9f4;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-10px, -10px);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform 0.5s linear;
}
div:hover::before{
  transform: translate(-10px, -10px) rotate(360deg);
}
div::after {
  content: "";
  height: 220px;
  width: 220px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid #e91e63;
  border-right-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-20px, -20px);
  z-index: -2;
  transition: transform 0.5s 0.5s linear;
}
div:hover::after{
  transform: translate(-20px, -20px) rotate(360deg);
}
```

Comment: Consider adding some commentary to your answer to describe how it answers the question.

Answer (score -4):

Just put the text/string 'HERE' in a anchor tag like this:

```
<a href="path/to/link.com">HERE</a>
```

Comment: How is your anwser supposed to solve the question?