# how can I add half round border inn after before of image

Tags: html, css

how can I add half round border inn after before of image
here is both images I need a half round border on right corner how can I achieve this
https://prnt.sc/1zdyyez
https://prnt.sc/1zdyyez

Comment: Can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13059190/html5-css3-circle-with-partial-border

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure thats not an image on the origin website? Otherwise I am not sure how to do it.

If you wanted curved borders then use the `border-radius` in your css.

What I mean: https://dabblet.com/gist/a89cbfd692275dca219ecb94ae95fb09