# Is it possible to make this button in Wordpress maybe through a plugin & how?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, figma

I got a custom button from a figma project to be implemented in a WordPress website but I am not sure how to make a button that would look like this in WordPress.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwCJN.png)

I tried to use some plugins like MaxButton but can't seem to make a button like the one in the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking at something like this. Ofcourse you need to add some more but this is close.

```css
    .button {display: inline-block; border-radius: 50px; background-color: #e84633; color: white; border: 7px solid #3c3c3b; padding: 10px 40px; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; position: relative;}

    .button::before,
    .button::after {
    position: absolute;
    width: 33px;
    height: 20px;
    content: "";
    }
    .button::before {
    left: -15px;
    top: -15px;
    border-left: 7px solid #3c3c3b;
    border-top: 7px solid #3c3c3b;
    
    border-radius: 50px 0 0 0;
    }

    .button::after {
    right: -15px;
    bottom: -15px;
    border-right: 7px solid #3c3c3b;
    border-bottom: 7px solid #3c3c3b;

    border-radius: 0 0 50px 0;
    }
```

```html
<a href="" class="button">view location</a>
```

Useful links:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius
2. https://unused-css.com/blog/css-partial-borders/
3. [Truncated or partial borders with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70610801/truncated-or-partial-borders-with-css)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I searched online for a way to do it but now I see I was searching for the wrong phrases. I very much appreciate the links at the end. They are exactly what I was trying to find but couldn't.